# How to get the current user in ListView?

Tags: django, django-views

How do I get the current user in the following implementation of the ListView. I would like to use the 'current user' in the `uname` argument of `reverse_lazy`

```
class ListMessages(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = Message
    template_name = 'accounts/list_messages.html'
    context_object_name = 'messages'
    form_class = MessageHiddenUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:list_messages', kwargs={'uname': })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do by overriding `success_url`

```
class ListMessages(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = Message
    template_name = 'accounts/list_messages.html'
    context_object_name = 'messages'
    form_class = MessageHiddenUserForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts:list_messages', kwargs={'uname': self.request.user.username })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a logged in user, you can call him in a view like this:

```
self.request.user
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Comment: best approach ever! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including success_url variable, you should override the function

```
def get_success_url(self):
     return reverse_lazy('accounts:list_messages', kwargs={'uname': self.request.user})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
class LineView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'object_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.request.user
    return queryset

template_name = "backend/line/list.html"
```